# Login cannot be done in my app

Tags: python, django

Login cannot be done in my app.I wrote in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from app.forms import RegisterForm,LoginForm
from app.models import Data
from app.forms import DataForm
from django.db.models import Q

def index(request):
    data = Data.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    form = RegisterForm()
    loginform = LoginForm()
    dataform = DataForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'data':data,'form':form,'loginform':loginform,'dataform':dataform,'user': request.user})
```

in index.html

```
<section id="top">
                {% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
                        <p>Hello</p>
                        <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
                {% else %}
                            <form action="{% url 'app:index' %}" method="POST">
                                    {{ loginform.non_field_errors }}

                                    {% for field in loginform %}
                                        {{ field }}
                                        {{ field.errors }}
                                    {% endfor %}

                                <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            </form>
                {% endif %}
</section>
```

in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
    AuthenticationForm
)
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = field.label
```

in child's app's urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.index,name='index'),
]
```

in parent's app's urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app/',include('app.urls') ),
]
```

When I login from loginform,if statement of `{% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}` did not become true.But when I login in admin site, the statement become true.When I put LOGIN button, no error happens.I really cannot understand what is wrong.How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your `index` view doesn't do anything when a `POST` request is submitted. It just initialises empty forms and returns them. You need to actually process the data that is submitted, authenticate the user and call the `login` method:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loginform = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if loginform.is_valid():  # this authenticates the user
            user = loginform.get_user()
            # redirect to success view or just render index.html
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'user': user})
        # else not needed, we go to the end and return the form with errors
    else:  # request method is 'GET'
        loginform = LoginForm()
        dataform = ...
        ...
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'data':data,'form':form,'loginform':loginform,'dataform':dataform,'user': request.user})
```

Comment: And if you want to handle the `dataform` and `registerform` in the same view, you'll have to add similar stuff to the `POST` part. Might make more sense to handle these posts in different views though (with a different URL)